# How to change image displayed on image browser?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, osx-snow-leopard, xcode3.2

I want to build an application that when the folder is drag and drop to my app, it will retain path and show custom image. so here is the screen shot of my app.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Ej7.png]

So as you can see in the screen shot, when i drag and drop folder on my app it will display the folder with the custom frame. So the problem is i want to change the folder icon shown in my app to other picture. I am still new to cocoa programming so i hope anyone can point what code to use to change the folder icon in my app. anyway i am using xcode 3.2 to build my app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to point to a directory that contains images. if you point to a directory that only contains directories, this is what you get.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i am not trying to display images contain in directory, but i just want to change that folder icon shown in my app to other icon.i just don't know what code to use to change the icon.